# Checking if items from a particular txt file agree to constraints in c++ - Name That Number USACO

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14

I have got some doubts while solving - Name That Number.
It goes like this -

Among the large Wisconsin cattle ranchers, it is customary to brand cows with serial numbers to please the Accounting Department. The cowhands don't appreciate the advantage of this filing system, though, and wish to call the members of their herd by a pleasing name rather than saying, "C'mon, #4734, get along."

Help the poor cowhands out by writing a program that will translate the brand serial number of a cow into possible names uniquely associated with that serial number. Since the cowhands all have cellular saddle phones these days, use the standard Touch-Tone(R) telephone keypad mapping to get from numbers to letters (except for "Q" and "Z"):

```
      2: A,B,C     5: J,K,L    8: T,U,V
      3: D,E,F     6: M,N,O    9: W,X,Y
      4: G,H,I     7: P,R,S
```

Acceptable names for cattle are provided to you in a file named "dict.txt", which contains a list of fewer than 5,000 acceptable cattle names (all letters capitalized). Take a cow's brand number and report which of all the possible words to which that number maps are in the given dictionary which is supplied as dict.txt in the grading environment (and is sorted into ascending order).

For instance, brand number 4734 produces all the following names:

GPDG GPDH GPDI GPEG GPEH GPEI GPFG GPFH GPFI GRDG GRDH GRDI
GREG GREH GREI GRFG GRFH GRFI GSDG GSDH GSDI GSEG GSEH GSEI
GSFG GSFH GSFI HPDG HPDH HPDI HPEG HPEH HPEI HPFG HPFH HPFI
HRDG HRDH HRDI HREG HREH HREI HRFG HRFH HRFI HSDG HSDH HSDI
HSEG HSEH HSEI HSFG HSFH HSFI IPDG IPDH IPDI IPEG IPEH IPEI
IPFG IPFH IPFI IRDG IRDH IRDI IREG IREH IREI IRFG IRFH IRFI
ISDG ISDH ISDI ISEG ISEH ISEI ISFG ISFH ISFI
As it happens, the only one of these 81 names that is in the list of valid names is "GREG".

Write a program that is given the brand number of a cow and prints all the valid names that can be generated from that brand number or ``NONE'' if there are no valid names. Serial numbers can be as many as a dozen digits long.

Here is what I tried to solve this problem. Just go through all the names in the list and check which is satisfying the constraints given.

```
int numForChar(char c){
    if     (c=='A'||c=='B'||c=='C') return 2;
    else if(c=='D'||c=='E'||c=='F') return 3;
    else if(c=='G'||c=='H'||c=='I') return 4;
    else if(c=='J'||c=='K'||c=='L') return 5;
    else if(c=='M'||c=='N'||c=='O') return 6;
    else if(c=='P'||c=='R'||c=='S') return 7;
    else if(c=='T'||c=='U'||c=='V') return 8;
    else if(c=='W'||c=='X'||c=='Y') return 9;
    else return 0;

int main(){

    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    freopen("namenum.in","r",stdin);
    freopen("namenum.out","w",stdout);

    string S; cin >> S;
    int len = S.length();

    freopen("dict.txt","r",stdin);

    string x;

    while(cin >> x){
        string currName = x;
        if(currName.length() != S.length()) continue;
        string newString = x;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            //now encode the name as a number according to the rules
            int num = numForChar(currName[i]);
            currName[i] = (char)num;
        }
        if(currName == S){
            cout << newString << "\n";
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I submit it to the judge, for some reason, it says no output produced that is my program created an empty output file. What's possibly going wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You.

UPDATE: I tried what Some Programmer Dude suggested by adding a statement `else return 0;` at the end of the `numOfChar` function in case of a different alphabet. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Your `numForChar` function is broken. What if the character is *not* one in the set you test for (for example`'Z'`, or something else (don't assume the input is always correct))? What do you return then?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your reply. I will check up on your query and let's see if it works!

Comment: Looks like you’ve forgotten about the “NONE” case.

Comment: @algrid What is the "NONE" case? Can you please elaborate a little? Thanks.

Comment: @Vasu090 In the problem description you have "...or ``NONE'' if there are no valid names...". Does your program ever print "NONE"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after looking further at the question and exploring the information for Name That Number. I realized that it is not a current contest, and just a practice challenge. Thus, I updated my answer and also giving you my version of a successful submission. Nonetheless, that is a spoiler and will be posted after why your code was not working.

First, you forgot a } after the declaration of your number function. Secondary, you did not implement anything to check whether if the input fail to yield a valid name. Third, when you use numForChar() on the character of currName, the function yielded an integer value. That is not a problem, the problem is that it is not the ASCII code but is a raw number. You then compare that against a character of the input string. Of which, is an ASCII's value of a digit. Thus, your code can't never find a match. To fix that you can just add 48 to the return value of the numForChar() function or xor the numForChar() return's value to 48.

You are on the right track with your method. But there is a few hints. If you are bored you can always skip to the spoiler. You don't need to use the numForChar() function to actually get a digit value from a character. You can just use a constant array. A constant array is faster than that many if loop.

For example, you know that A, B, C will yield two and A's ASCII code is 65, B's is 66, and C's equal to 67. For that 3, you can have an array of 3 indexes, 0, 1, 2 and all of them stores a 2. Thus, if you get B, you subtract B's ASCII code 65 will yield 1. That that is the index to get the value from.

For getting a number to a character you can have a matrix array of char instead. Skip the first 2 index, 0 and 1. Each first level index, contain 3 arrays of 3 characters that are appropriate to their position.

For dictionary comparing, it is right that we don't need to actually look at the word if the length are unequal. However, besides that, since their dictionary words are sorted, if the word's first letter is lower than the range of the input first letter, we can skip that. On the other hand, if words' first letter are now higher than the highest of the input first letter, there isn't a point in continue searching. Take note that my English for code commenting are almost always bad unless I extensively document it.

**Your Code(fixed):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int numForChar(char c){
    if     (c=='A'||c=='B'||c=='C') return 2;
    else if(c=='D'||c=='E'||c=='F') return 3;
    else if(c=='G'||c=='H'||c=='I') return 4;
    else if(c=='J'||c=='K'||c=='L') return 5;
    else if(c=='M'||c=='N'||c=='O') return 6;
    else if(c=='P'||c=='R'||c=='S') return 7;
    else if(c=='T'||c=='U'||c=='V') return 8;
    else if(c=='W'||c=='X'||c=='Y') return 9;
    else return 0;
}

int main(){

    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    ifstream fin("namenum.in");
    ifstream dict("dict.txt");
    ofstream fout("namenum.out");

    string S; 
    fin >> S;
    int len = S.length();
    bool match = false;

    string x;

    while(dict >> x){
        string currName = x;
        if(currName.length() != S.length()) continue;
        string newString = x;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            //now encode the name as a number according to the rules
            int num = numForChar(currName[i]) ^ 48;
            currName[i] = (char)num;
        }
        if(currName == S){
            fout << newString << "\n";
            match = true;
        }
    }

    if ( match == false ){
        fout << "NONE" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Spoiler Code(Improved):**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// A = 65
// 65 - 0 = 65
const char wToN[] = {
//  A ,B  ,C  ,D  ,E  ,F  ,G  ,H  ,I  ,
   '2','2','2','3','3','3','4','4','4',
// J  ,K  ,L  ,M  ,N  ,O  ,P  ,Q  ,R  ,S
   '5','5','5','6','6','6','7','7','7','7',
//  T  ,U  ,V  ,W  ,X  ,Y  ,Z
    '8','8','8','9','9','9','9'     
};
// 2 = {A, B, C} = 2[0] = A, 2[1] = B, 2[2] C
const char nToW[10][3] = {
    {}, // 0 skip
    {}, // 1
    {'A','B','C'},
    {'D','E','F'},
    {'G','H','I'},
    {'J','K','L'},
    {'M','N','O'},
    {'P','R','S'},
    {'T','U','V'},
    {'W','X','Y'}
};

int main(){

    ifstream fin("namenum.in");
    ifstream dict("dict.txt");
    ofstream fout("namenum.out");

    string S; 
    fin >> S;

    // Since this will not change
    // make this a const to make it 
    // run faster.
    const int len = S.length();
    // lastlen is last Index of length
    // We calculate this value here,
    // So we do not have to calculate 
    // it for every loop.
    const int lastLen = len - 1;
    int i = 0;
    unsigned char digits[len];
    unsigned char firstLetter[3];
    // If not match print None
    bool match = false;

    for (  ; i < len; i++ ){
      // No need to check upper bound
      // constrain did not call for check.
      if ( S[i] < '2' ) {
        fout << "NONE" << endl;
        return 0;
      }
    }

    const char digit1 = S[0] ^ 48;
    // There are 3 set of first letter.
    // We get them by converting digits[0]'s
    // value using the nToW array.
    firstLetter[0] = nToW[digit1][0];
    firstLetter[1] = nToW[digit1][1];
    firstLetter[2] = nToW[digit1][2];

    string dictStr;

    while(dict >> dictStr){
      // For some reason, when keeping the i = 0 here
      // it seem to work faster. That could be because of compiler xor.
      i = 0;
      // If it is higher than our range 
      // then there is no point contineuing.
      if ( dictStr[0] > firstLetter[2] ) break;

      // Skip if first character is lower
      // than our range. or If they are not equal in length
      if ( dictStr[0] < firstLetter[0] || dictStr.length() != len ) continue;

      // If we are in the letter range
      // we always check the second letter
      // not the first, since we skip the first
      i = 1;
      for ( int j = 1; j < len; j++ ){
        // We convert each letter in the word
        // to the corresponding int value
        // by subtracting the word ASCII value 
        // to 65 and use it again our wToN array.
        // if it does not match the digits at 
        // this current position we end the loop.
        if ( wToN[dictStr[i] - 65] != S[j] ) break;

        // if we get here and there isn't an unmatch then it is a match.
        if ( j == lastLen ) {
            match = true;
            fout << dictStr << endl;
            break;
        }
        i++;
      }
    }
    // No match print none.

    if ( match == false ){
        fout << "NONE" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the OPs question only pertained to the fact that he wasn't able to generate any output at all, which happened due to perhaps faulty file handling. The question was not about the problem itself.

Comment: @JatinSharma - Thank you for letting me know. It did seem to me that the OP wanted a final solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use c++ file handling. Overwriting stdin and stdout doesn't seem appropriate.

Add these,

```
std::ifstream dict ("dict.txt");
std::ofstream fout ("namenum.out");
std::ifstream fin ("namenum.in");
```

Accordingly change,

```
cin >> S  --to-->  fin >> S;
cin >> x  --to-->  dict >> x
cout << newString  --to--> fout << newString
```